# Are the rear brake mounts on my Boardman Team HT post-mount or IS?

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, disc-brake

[Boardman Team HT](http://www.boardmanbikes.com/mtb/ht_team.html)

Last weekend I broke the rear brake lever in a crash. I'm looking for a replacement brake disc kit for the rear brake, but I don't know what kind of mounting I've got. There seem to be two types, post-mount and IS (International Standard).

The shop I bought my bike from didn't have a manual when I bought it, I can't find one on-line, and the boardman website doesn't seem to have it or any contact info.

Which system does it have?

I'm pretty sure it's post-mount on the front as I've found a manual for the front fork.

Comment: When I bought my Avid BB7s, they included an adapter, which allowed them to be mounted on either post or IS. So it may not matter.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to look at the bike and take a look:

[image: International standard vs post mount]

It should be pretty straightforward to identify how the brake caliper is bolted to the frame.

Comment: So post mounts screw directly in, and the IS ones bolt through. Do the mountings look identical for the back brakes as they do for the pictured front ones?

Comment: For rear disks, I've only ever seen one type of mount. It looks like the IS - the screws go in from the side.

Comment: The Salsa Big Mama has rear post mounts, for example: http://salsacycles.com/files/bikes/bikes_bigmama7.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The stock brakes are [Avid Elixir 3](http://www.sram.com/news/avid-elixir-3-hydraulics-people). These are available in post and ISO mounts, but according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_brake#Advantages_and_disadvantages_of_various_types_of_mounts) post mounts are mostly used on the front brakes, with ISO mounts on the rear. This suggests to me that the kit likely has one of each - a post mount brake for the front and an ISO brake for the rear. Photos of the non-drive side are hard to find, but [this ebay one](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?VISuperSize&item=330541612643) seems to show an ISO mount.